# How to click one button that exists multiple times with same name using cypress?

Tags: click, cypress, contains

I have same button name on one page, how do handle that part?

Not sure how to do it, Can anyone help?

Comment: It would very much help both you and the community if you were to provide a sample html.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you can access the wanted button using .eq(), e.g.

```
cy.get("div.confirm:visible").eq(0).click({ force: true });
```

This would get you the first button, eq(1) would get you the second button and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CSS selector in `cy.get` then you can append `:first` or `:last` to the CSS selector

e.g.

`cy.get("div.foo:last").click()`